# How to convert milliseconds to Time(hh:mm:ss) in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, time, type-conversion

I would like to convert in PL/SQL miliseconds to Time(hh:mm:ss)

`21649000` to `06:00:49`

or

`83293000` to `23:08:13`

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: What data type is 'time' - just a string in that format? And can the original value ever be more than a day (86400000), and if so what should happen?

Comment: What is the desired output when the input is not a multiple of 1000? That is: if the input is 2500, that means 2.5 seconds, which cannot be represented in the format `hh:mi:ss`. (Notice `mi` which means minutes; `mm` as you wrote it will give you months, not minutes.) What is the desired result then?

Answer (score 2):

Use `NUMTODSINTERVAL` with `SECOND` option :

```
select NUMTODSINTERVAL( 83293000 / 1000, 'SECOND' ) "Time" from dual t;

Time
-------------------
+000000000 23:08:13
```

Comment: Or `83293000 / 1000 * INTERVAL '1' SECOND`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit if you move that from a comment to an answer, we can vote on it...

Answer (score 1):

This is a quite self-explanatory way:

```
select val,
       floor(     val / 1000 / 60 / 60       ) as hours,
       floor( mod(val / 1000 / 60      , 60) ) as minutes,
       floor( mod(val / 1000           , 60) ) as seconds
from (
        select 21649000 val from dual union 
        select 83293000 val from dual
     )

       VAL      HOURS    MINUTES    SECONDS
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
  21649000          6          0         49
  83293000         23          8         13
```

This does not handle days, so the number of milliseconds must be less than 24 hours.
This gives numbers, you can edit it the way you need to get your desired output format/type.

Comment: and if I want it as string?
060049 or 230813 ?

Comment: `to char` and `||`

Comment: @eyal1506 - Why `060049`? What happened to the colons? You said you wanted the result in the format `06:00:49`, has that changed?

Answer (score 1):

If you only want second precision you could divide the number by 1000 to get seconds, and by 86400 to get a fraction of a day, then add that to midnight on any nominal date - and convert the result to a string:

```
select to_char(date '1970-01-01' + (21649000/86400000), 'HH24:MI:SS') as time
from dual;

TIME    
--------
06:00:49

select to_char(date '1970-01-01' + (83293000/86400000), 'HH24:MI:SS') as time
from dual;

TIME    
--------
23:08:13
```

This only works properly for values less than a day, i.e. where your original number is less than 86400000; higher than that and you only see the leftover in the second day.

Answer (score 0):

The below query worked for me to convert to the Milliseconds to the HH:MM:SS

```
SELECT
TO_CHAR(TRUNC([ColumnName]/3600000),'FM9900') || ':' ||
TO_CHAR(TRUNC(MOD([ColumnName],3600000)/60000),'FM00') || ':' ||
TO_CHAR( trunc(MOD([ColumnName],60000)/1000),'FM00') FROM [TableName]`
```